# Django Rest Framework, "lookup_field" value that is defined on models level

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I faced with an issue in Django Rest Framework when I try to implement hyperlink related stuff.

Let's say there is a model with `slug` that is defined during `save` procedure

```
class Family(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.slug)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

So in my `serializers` package I have the following:

```
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ["name", "slug", "description", "url"]

        extra_kwargs = {
            "url": {"view_name": "api:family-detail", "lookup_field": "slug"},
            # I have to mark this field as not required one to be able POST wo this field
            "slug": {"required": False}
        }
```

When I try to create a new `Family` through `POST` request, of course, I'm getting 
`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'family-detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['api/families/(?P<slug>[^/.]+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/families/(?P<slug>[^/.]+)/$']` and `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:...` exception as well.

And here is my `ViewSet`:

```
class FamilyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    Provides CRUD operations on Family entity.
    """
    serializer_class = FamilySerializer
    queryset = Family.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "slug"
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
```

How to elaborate the issue I faced. Should I modify `FamilyViewSet` to generate `slug` on `ViewSet` level or take a look at "custom" `reverse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault/typo in `save` method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = self.name(self.slug)  # <-- must be self.name, but not self.slug
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```